# Problems with cyrillic alphabet when using babel

Tags: babel, mactex, cyrillic

I have installed MacTeX 2016 in a MacBookPro (OS 10.10.5), and I cannot "LaTeX", in TexShop a TeX-file containing cyrillic characters in the text.

My preamble:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb,amsxtra}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[koi8-r]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
```

And this is what I get:

[image]

**EDIT.** It works though with sudo latex in an xterm. Hence, it has to do with permissions.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your installation is broken: the `mkdir` command is trying to use a wrong path.

Comment: @egreg What should I do?

Comment: I've never seen anything like that. It seems some environment variable is set which shouldn't be.

Comment: @egreg Actually, I run in an xterm the command "sudo latex filename.tex" and it worked - Apparently, my Mac does not allow modifications of the installation of MacTeX

Comment: Hmm, you have misused `sudo`, it appears. Check the permissions in `/Users/yiorgos/Library`: everything in it should be accessible to the user.

Comment: I'd say `sudo chown -R yiorgos /Users/yiorgos/Library`

Comment: @egreg Wow, it worked! What a headache- Big Thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have apparently played with `sudo` in improper ways. The MacTeX version of TeX Live stores generated files on a user basis in

```
/Users/<user>/Library/texlive
```

and subdirectories thereof. These should have full access by the user, of course.

A simple strategy for resetting the ownership of the directories and files to the user is

```
sudo chown -R <user> /Users/<user>/Library/texlive
```

Change `<user>` into your name as shown by `whoami`, hit Return and all should be well.

A good general method on Unix systems to see what's the involved directory is to issue

```
kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFVAR
```

On a standard TeX Live this might return

```
/Users/<user>/.texlive<year>/texmf-var
```

(with `<year>` corresponding to the currently installed and active distribution). With MacTeX it returns

```
/Users/<user>/Library/texlive/2016/texmf-var
```

but running the `chown` command on the top level is probably better in order to reshape everything to normal.

---

Other Unix flavors of TeX Live might use

```
/home/<user>/.texlive
```